# fontsizeselect parameter not adding button in in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Here is my code that should add `fontsizeselect` to the menu:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea',
            plugins: 'lists',
            toolbar:
                "fontsizeselect undo redo | styleselect | bold italic |  outdent indent | numlist bullist",
            fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt"
        });
```

However the `fontsizeselect` button does not appear.

From [this article](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/available-toolbar-buttons/) it gives this command to show all available buttons
`tinyMCE.activeEditor.ui.registry.getAll().buttons`

However when I run it, the `fontsizeselect` parameter is not shown: [screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYubr.png)

I created my app by installing from npm with `npm install tinymce` found [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/).

I can't figure out what I am missing. Are there other things I need to install? I have tried in FF and Chrome.

EDIT: My code works when I am using the cloud version of TinyMCE, but I want to use the local version.